# Vue infinite loop ... in method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am getting this warning `[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.` and I think I know why it's happening.

My Use Case :
I have a loop where I am passing an object with index to a vue method. Since computed cannot have arguments so I cannot use it. The remaining option is method.

I am trying to increase the date by one week after the loop reaches to a odd number. Only 1 and 2 is an exception.

Here is my code I have been trying to use

```
getDate(date, i){
      var currentDate=date.startingDate

      var res=currentDate
      if(i>2){
        // change the date 
         if(i%2==0){
            //use previous dates 
            res=date.startingDate
         }else{
            // increase the date by one week from the last week 
            var currDate = new Date(currentDate)
            var d=currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() + 7);
            var d=new Date(d)
            var newDate=d.toISOString()
            var dateArr=newDate.split("T")
            var res=dateArr[0]
            console.log('ok')

            date.startingDate=res // this line is the problem and causes the infinite loop problem.  

         }
      }

      return res

  }
```

Here `date.startingDate` is always a fixed date.

Sample Input

`date.startingDate='2018-05-11'`

so when `i=1, and 2 (i always starts from 1)` 
out put is `date.startingDate='2018-05-11'`

when `i=3,4` date should increase by one week so expected out put is `2018-05-17`

The problem is `date.startingDate=res` I cannot reset the date to this one. But I have to reset it to the increased new date in order to be able to add new date when `i=5,6 or bla bla`.

Any suggested solutions in other ways or may be this code can be made better in a different ways? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you so much for the time.

**Edit**

```
<div class="row _6-2-1__Tou align-items-center team" v-for="(m,j) in data.row" :key="j">


     <div class="col-auto _6-2-1__Tou-one pad-0" >
       <ul class="_6-2-1__Tou-text">

        <li>{{getDate(m.date,j+1)}}</li>

      </ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code which have v-for?

Comment: Thanks. See the edited question now

Comment: I check your getDate function and it seems ok https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/LmrzMr

Comment: Thank you. This way it will work. Actually vue js calls this method if any change happens in data. since I am changing date, it calls this method again and again. This causes infinite loop problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems impossible to avoid this problem. So I changed my approach. I didn't update the date while populating the doom, instead, I used vuex store and getters. When returning from getters, I changed the values there and once all date changes are done, I simply returned the array. It worked nicely. Here is my code

This code is a bit changed in terms of logic as I added dynamic conditions. But concept is same.

```
fixture(state){
  // we can actually update here

  for(var i in state.fixture){

      var details=state.fixture[i].row
      for(var j in details){   
          //console.log(details[j].date.startingDate)

          if(state.counter==state.groupCount){  

              // increase the date 
             if(state.date){
              var currDate = new Date(state.date) 
            }else{
              var currDate = new Date(details[j].date.startingDate) 
            }

              var d=currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() + 7);  
              var d=new Date(d)
              var newDate=d.toISOString()
              var dateArr=newDate.split("T")
              var res=dateArr[0]
              details[j].date.startingDate=res 

              state.date=details[j].date.startingDate   

              state.counter=1

          }else{

            if(state.date){ 
              details[j].date.startingDate=state.date 
            }

            state.counter++ 
          }

      }
      state.counter=0
      state.date=''
  }

  return state.fixture
},
```

Hope this approach helps others.